# PHP shell_exec Net Use Output

Tags: php, output, shell-exec, net-use

I have the following php command:

1. $shellOutput = shell_exec('net use');

I receive the following output:

```
Status  Local   Remote      Network

OK            S:    \\srv\dataS     Microsoft Windows Network
```

When I run net use in a cmd window I receive the following output

```
 Status Local   Remote      Network

 OK           L:    \\srv\dataL Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           M:    \\srv\dataM Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           P:    \\srv\dataP Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           R:    \\srv\dataR Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           S:    \\srv\dataS Microsoft Windows Network
```

Should all the mapped network drives display or does PHP limit the number of drives returned?

If the command supposed to return more than 1 network drive, please provide short example on who to get more than one row to return.

TIA

---

After performing the var_dump, the value returned was

```
Status  Local   Remote      Network

OK      S:      \\srv\dataS     Microsoft Windows Network
```

Answer (score 0):

**shell_execute** should return the complete output as a string, please make sure, you ***are not*** using **exec**.

1. Make sure, the user who is running the code (apache, www-data, httpd,etc)  has the right permission for connecting all the network drivers.
2. Can you please,let me know what are you trying to achieve?

Unfortunately, I do not have a Windows environment, and I can not test Windows commands. However; Linux commands work as expected with **shell_exec** (output as a string)

Please let me know

Comment: I am trying to pass a fully quailified file name (server/directory(ies)/filename and extension.  The file will eventually be read into a database using BCP and further processed once on the dataabse.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that when I upload the data into the database, the table names are different based up the user who uploads the data.  At the time the files are selected I do not have the information on the user who selected the files.